# How can i create a portrait video using Android's MediaRecorder

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, commonsware-cwac

I have an Android application which is able to record and play a videos in portrait mode, those features are working fine on Android phones.

The issue comes up because this video is needed to be played also on iOS devices (after being shared through a server).

iOS is not correctly showing the video as it looks "cropped", but videos recorded on iOS are played without issues.

So, the main difference between videos created on Android and iOS' is the size and the rotation.

Im using [CWAC-Camera](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) library for preview and recording and ffmpeg to scale the video down to 320x568px (as this is the standard size for both Android and iOS apps).

Here is the metadata from an video created from Android:

```
General
Complete name                            : android_video.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 447 KiB
Duration                                 : 5s 596ms
Overall bit rate                         : 654 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Writing application                      : Lavf56.4.101

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L2.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 5s 406ms
Bit rate                                 : 536 Kbps
Width                                    : 568 pixels
Height                                   : 320 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Original display aspect ratio            : 16:9
Rotation                                 : 270°
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 14.985 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.197
Stream size                              : 354 KiB (79%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=14 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 5s 596ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 132 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel(s)_Original                      : 1 channel
Channel positions                        : Front: C
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 89.4 KiB (20%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
```

And here is the metadata from the video created on iOS:

```
General
Complete name                            : ios_video.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42
File size                                : 673 KiB
Duration                                 : 7s 38ms
Overall bit rate                         : 783 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-03-17 19:16:36
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-03-17 19:16:37

Video
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 7s 33ms
Bit rate                                 : 711 Kbps
Width                                    : 320 pixels
Height                                   : 568 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 0.563
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.130
Stream size                              : 610 KiB (91%)
Title                                    : Core Media Video
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-03-17 19:16:36
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-03-17 19:16:37
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
Color range                              : Limited

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 7s 38ms
Source duration                          : 7s 105ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 64.0 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel(s)_Original                      : 1 channel
Channel positions                        : Front: C
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 56.8 KiB (8%)
Source stream size                       : 57.2 KiB (9%)
Title                                    : Core Media Audio
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-03-17 19:16:36
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-03-17 19:16:37
```

The values width and height are inverted on Android, also the Rotation parameter is set to 270º (this is the rotation parameter for portrait videos).

This is a sketch of how iOS' videos look on iOS app:

[image: Videos recorded on iOS]

And this is how Android's videos look on iOS app:

[image]

So, in order to get the videos correctly displayed both on iOS and Android i need to be able to set the width to 320 and height to 568 on Android. I tried it from several places (outside and inside CWAC-Camera library) but i always get a Camera.Parameters error.

It is possible to do this on Android?

**EDIT:**

This is the result i get when i set the rotation to 0 with ffmpeg:

[image]

Comment: You can't invent your own resolutions, if that's what you mean. If it's not a supported video size, it's not a supported video size. I'd use `ffmpeg` to rotate the video.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I my case iOS is not taking the rotation into account (it just take width and height), so i'm afraid it is not an option. Anyway, you're right, i cannot set that's specific resolution but it seems that i cannot set any resolution with 9:16 either...i guess this is not possible at all in Android

Comment: "I my case iOS is not taking the rotation into account (it just take width and height), so i'm afraid it is not an option" -- I don't understand. If you rotate the video, and change the headers to reflect the fact that players don't need to rotate it themselves ("the Rotation parameter is set to 270º" -- change this to 0), it should be fine on iOS, right? After all, it will be an actual portrait video, orientation-wise and resolution-wise.

Comment: "If you rotate the video, and change the headers to reflect the fact that players don't need to rotate it themselves ("the Rotation parameter is set to 270º" -- change this to 0), it should be fine on iOS, right? After all, it will be an actual portrait video, orientation-wise and resolution-wise." It doesn't actually. I'm aware that the AVPlayer view in this iOS app was customized but if i set the Rotation (using ffmpeg) not only iOS is showing it in landscape mode, but also is Android and Mac OSX. I just added a screenshot from a video with Rotation=0, width:568px and height:320px.

Comment: And when you view a video that is rotation=0, width=320, height=568, what do you get? If you are starting with a video that is rotation=270, width=568, and height=320 (see your Android metadata), and you rotate it -270, you will get rotation=0, width=320, height=568. You should not get rotation=0, width=568, height=320 -- that's what you would get if you just zero out the rotation header and don't rotate the video.

Comment: You're totally right! i was not setting the rotation of the video but only the header!! I think this resolves the issue. Thank you!

Comment: If you ever publish your `ffmpeg` recipe, let me know. :-)

Comment: I will add it to the question! I'm still working on that ;)